# What sort of materials can I use to make a latex mask look wet without actually being wet?

Tags: material-selection, costume-design

So Halloween is approaching, and I'm thinking about sitting on the porch to pass out candy, except wearing a [mindflayer](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_flayer) costume, because there is only one day a year when scaring other peoples kids is acceptable (but only if you give them candy).

I'm thinking of starting with this [ood mask from dr who](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K82SMQO) and fabricating extra tentacles out of rubber snake toys, but I also want the mask to look like it's covered in slime like a regular octopus would be. I had entertained the idea of using petroleum jelly, but that would be gross and greasy.

What can I cover the mask with so that it looks wet and oozy while still being at least somewhat comfortable and dry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main things that make objects look wet:

1. The glossy, reflective finish that water has
2. The shape and depth of the water - you can see not just the surface of the water, but the surface of the object below it

Anything that satisfies these properties will work.

Given that you probably want the tentacles to remain flexible, I would recommend **clear silicone sealant** to make the volume of the ooze, adding drops to the end of tentacles etc, followed by a coat of **flexible gloss varnish** for the reflective finish.